# Rspec periodically hangs when using capybara-webkit with a page that loads an external script with async = true

Tags: javascript, rspec, capybara, freeze, capybara-webkit

I'm working on an application that uses uservoice.  The uservoice snippet

```
  var uv = document.createElement('script');
  uv.type = 'text/javascript';
  uv.async = true;
  uv.src = ...; // external call to uservoice to fetch js
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  ...
```

This javascript is loaded on all pages.  When running `rake spec` the run will periodically hang.  All tests run smoothly when I remove the uservoice snippet.  I've tried setting `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit_debug` and I see no response from uservoice.  When I set `page.driver.browser.timeout` I can see a 0 response from uservoice and the specs will fail with a timeout error.

Anyone else encounter this problem?

Comment: I had something similar, but was resolved by using the most modern version of ruby/capybara/rspec.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced timeout errors while waiting for an external script to lead (e.g. google analytics) when my development machine becomes disconnected from the internet.

I still sometimes use firebug and selenium driver when I'm trying to debug capybara as it can be illuminating to see an actual browser go at it.